# VS 2012 Debugging with IIS

Tags: debugging, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have a web application in visual studio with several different projects. It is running on IIS locally for debugging purposes. I am using the extension "AttachTo" to attach the debugger to the IIS site. The debugging works for the main project but when I try to add a break point to one of the other projects which are just libraries of functions, visual studio says the breakpoint will not be hit because no symbols were loaded.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to build your projects with Full Debug Info so that PDB files are generated. Not sure how to do it in 2012, but in 2010 you right click the project, go to the "Build" tab, then "Advanced" and select "Full" for "Debug Info"

Comment: I checked this. It is already set to Full for debug info on the web project. The other projects do not have this option in their properties.

Comment: Gotcha. That's about the limit of advanced debugging I have. I do know that you will need to somehow get the PDBs for those other projects, I just can't give you concrete instructions on how to do so. Good luck, though.